# Grafting a dying guava cutting

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, grafting, guavas

This is a rare variety (pink guava) here and hard to get. This plant appears to be dying as other of its siblings have started to grow nicely. I don't want to lose this. I see it is still green inside. But I don't think it is going to grow new leaves as I have given it enough time.

Is it a good idea to graft a part of it on a local commonly available guava (white flesh)?

[image]

Comment: Worth a try., why not?

Comment: If you drop the word "a", your question title has some beautiful trochaic quadrameter... Sorry for the irreverence :)